# How to solve $f'(x)=f'(\frac{x}{2})$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

How do we solve this given $f'(0)=-1$. It does not look separable. I can integrate both sides but end up with a functional equation with is not helpful.

Comment: As you only have $f'$ in the equation, it's not really a differential equation. It's "just" a functional equation for $f'$.

Comment: Let's clarify the functional equation by saying that $f$ is a function of a single real variable and for all $x:$ $\left.\frac{df(t)}{dt}\right|_{t=x} = \left.\frac{df(t)}{dt}\right|_{t=x/2}$ and $\left.\frac{df(t)}{dt}\right|_{t=0} = -1$.  Is that what the OP means?

Comment: @MarkFischler sorry I didn't really see your comment, I see that it is a functional equation and yes it could mean that. But that wouldn't change the answer would it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will assume that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is supposed to be $C^1$, so $f'$ exists and is continuous everywhere.  Now note that for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $f'(x)=f'(x/2)=f'(x/4)=f'(x/8)=\cdots$.  But $x/2^n$ converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, so continuity of $f'$ now implies $$-1=f'(0)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f'(x/2^n)=f'(x).$$  So $f'(x)=-1$ for all $x$, and thus $f(x)=-x+C$ for some constant $C$.

In fact, the assumption that the derivative is continuous can be eliminated, as explained in detail in Robert Israel's answer.

Comment: I don't think you need to assume $f'$ continuous

Comment: Cool  I've used your answer in another answer is that ok?

Comment: You definitely don't need to assume $f'$ continuous, but it requires a lot of fiddling

Comment: @Shakespeare What method would you use to prove it without $f'$ continuous?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla: Sure, just provide a link to my answer as attribution.

Comment: @Winther: There does not exist any function $f$ which has your function as its derivative.  I believe the the continuity assumption can be removed, but at the moment don't quite see how to fill in all the details.

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah, I missed that one, I just read it as a simple functional equation. You are probably right then, the condition that it has to be the derivative of a function should remove alot of these otherwise strange solutions.

Comment: @EricWofsey I think we can argue as follows in the general case: since $f$ is differentiable it has to be continuous. Integrating the functional equation gives us $f(x) - 2f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = -f(0)$ and since $f$ is continuous with $f'(0)=-1$ we get the desired solution $f(x) = -x + f(0)$ with the same type of argument as you have in your answer.

Comment: @Winther: Is it true that any everywhere differentiable function is equal to the integral of its derivative?  (Maybe this is standard, but I can never remember the exact hypotheses you need on these statements.)

Comment: Oh, actually, I think you can get that identity on $f$ without integrating.  I'll fill in the details later (assuming they work...).

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus I guess. All we need here is that if $g$ is differentiable with $\frac{dg(x)}{dx} = 0$ then $g(x)$ (which here is $f(x) - 2f(x/2)$) is a constant.

Comment: Right, that's the argument I had in mind, more or less.

Answer (score 10):

Suppose $f$ is differentiable everywhere on $\mathbb R$ and $f'(x) = f'(x/2)$ for all $x$. 
Now $$\dfrac{d}{dx} \left(f(x) - 2 f(x/2)\right) = f'(x) - f'(x/2) = 0$$
so $f(x) - 2 f(x/2)$ must be constant, say $f(x) - 2 f(x/2) = c$.  $f$ is continous at $0$ since it is differentiable there, and taking the limit as $x \to 0$ we find $c = -f(0)$.  Since the problem is invariant under addition of a constant, we may assume for convenience $f(0)=0$, so $f(x) = 2 f(x/2)$.

Defining $$ g(t) = 2^{-t} f(2^t)$$
we find
$$ g(t) = 2^{-t} f(2^t) = 2^{1-t} f(2^{t-1}) = g(t-1) $$
i.e. $g$ is periodic with period $1$.

Now we need $f$ to be differentiable at $0$. We get
$$ f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0+} g(\log_2 x) = \lim_{t \to -\infty} g(t)$$
But in order for this limit to exist, given that $g$ is periodic, $g$ must be constant; if $f'(0)=-1$ that constant is $-1$, and $f(x) = 2^{\log_2 x} g(\log_2 x) = -x$.
Similarly, looking at $2^{-t} f(-2^t)$ we find that $f(x) = -x$ for $x < 0$.
Removing the assumption $f(0)=0$, the general solution is $f(x) = -x + k$.

Comment: A different (and perhaps simpler) variant of the final argument: Since $f(x) = 2f(x/2)$ then $f(x) = 2^n f(x/2^n) \implies f(x) = x\frac{f(x/2^n) - f(0)}{x/2^n} \to x f'(0)$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Why didn't you get $f(x)=-x+k$ or is that just a typo?

Comment: Sorry, I took $f'(0) = 1$ instead of $-1$.  Edited it.

Comment: This is what I had in mind when I said we don't need to assume $f'$ continuous, but wasn't bothered to write it out. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

This is a functional equation for $g(x)=f'(x)$ and the solution is $g(x)=\varphi(\log x)$ where $\varphi(x)=\varphi(x-\log 2)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with period $\log 2$.

In fact for the equation $g(ax)=bg(x)$ we have $g(aa^x)=bg(a^x)$ and 
$g(a^{x+1})=bg(a^x)$; then $g(a^x)=\varphi(x)b^x$, where $\varphi(x)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period.

Finally $g(x)=\varphi(\log_ax)x^{\log_ab}$. For $a=1/2$ and $b=1$, $g(x)=\varphi(\log x)$ where $\varphi(x)=\varphi(x-\log 2)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with period $\log 2$.

For $\varphi(x)=C$ constant, we have the particular solution $g(x)=f'(x)=C$ that is $f(x)=Cx+k$ and from $f'(0)=-1$ we have $f(x)=-x+k$.

Comment: why downvote???

Comment: Not every function such function $g$ constructed from a periodic $\varphi$ can be the derivative of a function.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously $f'(x)=-1$ solves this, taking the anti derivative we get the solution $f(x)=-x+k$.