# if $f(\frac{x+y}{2}) =\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$ then find $|f(2)|$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, functional-equations

if the following functional equation  $$f\bigg(\frac{x+y}{2}\bigg) =\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2} \quad \text{ holds for all real }~ x  ~\text{ and }~ y$$  If$f'(0)$ exists and equals to $-1$ then find $|f(2)|$.

**My work**

I tried to find $f'(x)$ so that i can intregrate it and then find $f(x)$

$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

which gave me this equation:

$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(2x)-2f(x)+1+f(2h)-1}{2h}$

I could not proceed further

and the answer is $2$

Comment: Is the bracket like the greatest integer function or something, or is it just superfluous? Also you say $f'(x)=-1$, where does that hold? If it holds everywhere then the first piece of information is totally irrelevant, and you just have $f(2)=-2$ so $|f(2)|=2$.

Comment: i have edditted that bracket, plus the question didn't mention where it holds true but i assume it holds true, i assume it might hold true wherever the function is differentiable

Comment: What have you tried? Show your working as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$, then find $f(2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800026/if-f-fracxy2-fracfxfy2-then-find-f2)

Comment: @Aniket so, you wanna say given conditions are made up by you,

Comment: @Sil it doesn't meet the conditions given by op.

Comment: @Subhajit Not exactly, but that is not required for a duplicate, it is basically the same problem.

Comment: "i have edditted that bracket"  You've edited the brackets to mean what exactly?  The question was what do the brackets mean.  Ian asked if they meant the greatest integer function.  Or if they were just parenthesis.  *Do* they mean the greatest integer function or *are* they just parethesis?

Comment: Perhaps the question is to assume the functional equation and that $f'(x_0)=-1$ for some single point $x_0$, then you need to use the functional equation to deduce $f'(x)=-1$ everywhere else (after which you get what I said).

Comment: @fleablood i edditied that bracket as I wrongly placed them in the question, as im pretty new so i'm still figuring out.

Comment: @Subhajit no i didnt made up the conditions this is exactly how this question is printed in my book

Comment: @Aniket if f'(x)=-1 for all x with the condition f(0)=0,then it refers to just the integration calculation! And there is nothing to do with the part f((x+y)/2)=(f(x)+f(y))/2.

Comment: @Aniket Now you have removed the condition $f(0)=0$ and the question is ambiguous, there is no unique answer (any $f(x)=-x+c$ will do the job)

Comment: You can also take a screenshot of the question and then post it here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image: answer]

since $f'(0)=-1$

we get $f'(x)=-1$

we can integrate both sides and put $x=2$

(and also sorry for mistakes in question. I'm new, so this all was a bit hard and I made silly mistakes)

so we get $|f(x)|=2$

Comment: Integrating $-1$ you get $-x+c$. So putting $x=2$ you get $f(2)=-2+c$. You miss some information to be able to determine the constant, it was most likely included in the original problem definition.

Answer (score 2):

If the brackets are not the greatest integer function, then, It's [Jensen's Functional Equation](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/FuncEq-Intro/FuncEq-Intro.pdf) and the solution is $f(x) = ax + b~$ for real $a~$ and $~b.$

Therefore from the given, we have

$$ f(0) = b = 0 ~\text{ and }~ f'(x) = a = - 1$$
Therefore the function is
$$ f(x) = -x \implies \lvert f(2)\rvert = 2 $$

Comment: just a note: if $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies this equation, it is not necessarily linear. we need some sort of additional constraint (e.g. here, continuity at a point) in order to conclude that $f(x)=ax+b$. see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) for more details

Comment: No, initially (before editing) the question said that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence $f$ was continuous. That's why I said linear @user574848

Comment: yep, i'm not saying your answer is wrong (since f is continuous at 0, it's linear as you've stated). just informing OP/readers that you can't directly conclude it's linear without constraints

Answer (score -1):

$$f'(x) = -1$$
Integrate both sides
$$f(x) = -x $$
$$|f(2)| = 2 $$

Comment: okay, but how did you reach $f'(x)= -1$ could you explain that and the answer is actually $1$

Comment: Your question states it clearly "If f′(x) exists and equals to −1....."

Comment: Wait .. I forgot to calculate the constant of integration

Comment: That must be -1,

Comment: @TimCrosby $f(0)=0$, so $C=0$

Comment: Sorry...:(, didn't see that.

Comment: Nevermind, now it was removed by OP, so who knows :)